# 10進数255までを2進数に変換し、新規作成したテキストファイルに書き込む

Tags: perl

255までの10進数を2進数に変換する命令は分かりましたが、open関数でテキストファイルに書き込むことができません。
繰り返し文の二重化を避けるため、foreach文をサブルーチンにして、テキストファイルを作成するときは、サブルーチンから参照するようにしました。
結果、参照は可能ですが、テキストファイルには何も反映されませんでした。

```
sub math {
    foreach my $c ( 0..255 ) {
        my $str3 = sprintf('%b', $c);
        print $c , ' -> ' , $str3 , "\n";
    }
}


my @line = &math;
open (OUT, ">>index.txt") or die "cannot open texfile : $!\n";
foreach (@line) {
    print OUT @line;
}

close(OUT);
```

Comment: 避けるというよりまさに二重化しているような・・・

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 結果、参照は可能ですが、テキストファイルには何も反映されませんでした。

参照してません。print で画面に出力しているだけです。関数 math から何も戻り値を返してないです。

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub math {
  my @a; 
  push @a, sprintf("%d -> %b\n", $_, $_) for ( 0..255 );
  @a
}

my @line = &math;
open (my $f, ">>", "index.txt") or die "cannot open texfile : $!\n";
print $f $_ for @line;
close($f);
```

> 繰り返し文の二重化を避けるため、foreach文をサブルーチンにして、テキストファイルを作成するときは、サブルーチンから参照するようにしました。

`繰り返し文の二重化`が良く分かりませんが、この程度の処理ならば関数化しなくても良いかと。

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open (my $f, ">>", "index.txt") or die "cannot open texfile : $!\n";
printf $f "%d -> %b\n", $_, $_ for ( 0..255 );
close($f);
```

Comment: `print $f @line for @line;` は、`print $f $_ for @line;` の(質問者の)間違いだと思います。また、`">>"` はタイトルから`">"` の(これも質問者のですが)間違いだと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。やり方が間違っているのは分かりました。

Answer (score 1):

いくつかの問題があるように見えますが，今回のような場合だと内容の確認のために use Data::Dumper をして，my @line = &math; のあとに print Dumper \@line をして @line の内容を確認するのが良いかと思います．

```
my @line = &math;
# @line は期待するものが入っているのかを確認する (print debug)
print Dumper \@line;
```